# Python index error parse_results = result.get("Parsed Results")[0]

Tags: python, json, api, ocr, ocrspace-ocr-api

I am using the OCRSpace API and I have never received this error message before. The OCR always has worked on this image but recently gave me `IndexError: list index out of range` for: `parse_results = result.get("Parsed Results")[0]`. The full code is:

```
url_api = "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image"
            result = requests.post(url_api,
                          files = {os.path.join(path, file_name): file_bytes},
                          data = {"apikey": "KEY",
                                  "language": "eng",
                                  #"OCREngine": 2,
                                  "isTable": True})
            result = result.content.decode()
            result = json.loads(result)
            parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
            global OCRText
            OCRText = parsed_results.get("ParsedText")
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: it looks like the "ParsedResults" field of result is a empty list.

Comment: It has worked in the past, could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: What does `result.content.decode()` return?

Comment: basically when you have converted the results to json. the result becomes a dictionary. and the value of `result['ParsedResults'] = []` which is empty list and if you try accessing empty list using index 0, it raises IndexError. It is a server side problem or the results for that were none

Comment: try inserting `from pprint import pprint; pprint(result)` after the `result = json.loads(result)` line. and then share the output to us. (Complete output)

Comment: The response is: 'ParsedResults': [{'ErrorDetails': '',    
                    'ErrorMessage': '',    
                    'FileParseExitCode': 1,
                    'ParsedText': '16375 N. Kashington St.\t\r\n'
                                  'Thornton, CO 80023\t\r\n'
                                  '2X Member 111826278335\t\r\n'
                                  '673919 FF \t23.99 E\t\r\n'
                                  '633561 KS DICED TOH\t\r\n'
                                  '967596 JACKORGSALSR\t2.97 E\t\r\n'
                                  '3 e 4.29\t\

Comment: The code stops working and starts working randomly